# Trouble using PHP to parse an XML document with identical tags

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Here is a snippet from yahoo Weather showing the identical tags

```
<yweather:forecast day="Mon" date="16 Jan 2012" low="-1" high="6" text="Clear" code="31"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Tue" date="17 Jan 2012" low="3" high="7" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34"/>
```

To access the day in the first tag I use the following function:

```
function get_forecast_day(SimpleXMLElement $xml) {

    // Pull forecast day
    $forecast['day'] = $xml->channel->item->children('yweather', TRUE)->forecast->attributes()->day;
    echo $forecast['day'] . ", ";

return $day;
}
```

Any ideas how I can access the day in the second tag.  Obviously searching for the value "Tue" is no good as these values will change daily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `item` not also a function? Something like `$xml->channel->item(0)->children ...` or `$xml->channel->item(1)->children ... `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->forecast` can be used as array, so go for second element with index `1`:

```
$xml->channel->item->children('yweather', TRUE)->forecast[1]->attributes()->day
```